# What will be the best suited datatype to store a text file in database

Tags: sql-server, blob, filestream

I want to store a text file containing logs in a database(SQL Server). That file size can vary from 1 MB to 10 MB. what will best suited data type to store it in to the database. Will it be BLOB or FILESTREAM or any other type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your files are going to be >1MB, then FILESTREAM is your best option. You can look at BOL documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/gg471497.aspx), which clearly describes and advises you when is the best situation to use it.